# I want to draw rectangle with double edges in Tkinter library in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, shapes

I can draw rectangle with one edge using the below code

```
self.canvas.create_rectangle(
    self.start_x, self.start_y, self.end_x, self.end_y, outline="black", fill="grey", width=self.width)
```

But how to draw two edges like in weak entity in ER Diagram?

Comment: Are you referring to something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity)? Not familiar with Tkinter, but can't you just draw two rectangles, with the smaller one on top of the larger one? That could simulate a double edge.

Answer (score 2):

How about draw a second, slightly larger rectangle around the first?

```
self.canvas.create_rectangle(
    self.start_x - 0.02,
    self.start_y - 0.02,
    self.end_x + 0.02,
    self.end_y + 0.02,
    outline="black",
    fill="",
    width=self.width
)
```

Comment: but it is drawing it as a separate rectangle , what I want is a single shape and not two different shapes

Comment: @harshitagarwal: you can't draw a single shape with two edges. This answer is correct: if you want two edges, draw two rectangles.